# Setting a specific location for a label in Java

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm currently working on a project, and I'm trying to set my label to be in a certain place, this is what my code currently looks like;

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class First extends JFrame 
{
    private JLabel label;
    private JTextField textfield;

        JLabel ZKey;
    public First()
    {
        ZKey=new JLabel("ZKey");
        ZKey.setLayout(null);
        ZKey.setLocation(55, 55);
        add(ZKey);
    }

public static void main (String args[])
{
    First gui = new First ();
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gui.setSize(500,500);
    gui.setVisible(true);
    gui.setTitle("Keep Track Of What You Press");
}
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something rather silly.

Comment: What, exactly, is it doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, it basically places the label in the middle on the far left, I can't seem to get it to be anywhere else.

Comment: Try using pack() on gui, after adding the JLabel and before setting gui visible.
Anyway, in most cases you don't really want a null-layout but some kind of layout manager

Answer (score 0):

Use a JPanel, add the JLabel to the panel, add the panel to the JFrame. Label appears top and center now:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class First extends JFrame 
{
    private JLabel label;
    private JTextField textfield;

        JLabel ZKey;
        JPanel panel;
    public First()
    {
        panel=new JPanel();
        ZKey=new JLabel("ZKey");
        ZKey.setLayout(null);
        ZKey.setLocation(55, 55);
        panel.add(ZKey);
        add(panel);
    }

public static void main (String args[])
{
    First gui = new First ();
    //gui.setLayout(null);
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gui.setSize(500,500);
    gui.setVisible(true);
    gui.setTitle("Keep Track Of What You Press");
}
}
```